# Нахождение НОД, увеличение коэффициента в 0,5 для каждых двух прохождений

Tags: алгоритм

В книге Рода Стивенсона "Алгоритмы", сказано:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***A*** - первое значение, ***B*** - второе, ***R*** - остаток
Непонятно почему в конце *B<sub>1</sub>-R<sub>1</sub>=B<sub>1</sub> mod R<sub>1</sub>*
Например, для значений 128 и 12 это справедливо:
*A<sub>1</sub>=128, B<sub>1</sub>=12, R<sub>1</sub>=8*
*B<sub>1</sub>-R1=4, B<sub>1</sub> mod R<sub>1</sub>=4.

**4=4***
Но, например, для чисел 2602 и 256 это несправедливо:
*A<sub>1</sub>=2602, B<sub>1</sub>=256, R<sub>1</sub>=42*

*B<sub>1</sub>-R1=214, B<sub>1</sub> mod R<sub>1</sub>=4

**214!=4***
Или я что-то неправильно понял?

Comment: Ну так как минимум есть же слова. Больше можно...

Comment: @pavel это я понял, но почему B1-R1 = B1 mod R1?

Comment: Мне кажется там написано... Предполагают что уменьшение меньше чем в 2 раза, значит только 1 раз r1 вычли. От противного. А вообще зачем вы это разбираете? На слово поверьте)